# Styling issue in ASPX page

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net

I have an ASPX page that is suppose to output 5 instances of one custom control (basically a table with data grabbed from a database). I am relatively new to ASP.NET as well as JavaScript, so I am having some difficulty fixing this styling issue.

My problem is that, styling on the custom control (the table) is only being applied to the first instance of the control. I am not sure why that is. I have put my code up (I renamed a lot of things to keep this generic). How would I go about making the styling apply to all 5 instances?

```
<%@ Register Assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX" Namespace="System.Web.UI" TagPrefix="asp" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="company" TagName="Control3" Src="~/Common/Controls/Control3.ascx" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="<%=ResolveUrl("~/Project/Css/Dashboard.css") %>" />
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <div id="dashboardContent">

        <div id="id1">

            <%-- ID1 --%>
            <div class="roundedTop">
                <asp:Label ID="lblID1" runat="server" CssClass="InputHeader" meta:resourcekey="lblID1" />
            </div>

            <div class="roundedMain"><!--<![endif]-->

                <company:Control3 ID="control3First" runat="server" meta:resourcekey="control3First"
                    Filter="" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="id2">

            <%-- ID2 --%>
            <div class="roundedTop">
                <asp:Label ID="lblID2" runat="server" CssClass="InputHeader" meta:resourcekey="lblID2" />
            </div>

            <div class="roundedMain"><!--<![endif]-->

                <company:Control3 ID="control3Second" runat="server" meta:resourcekey="control3Second"
                    Filter="" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="id3">

            <%-- ID3 --%>
            <div class="roundedTop">
                <asp:Label ID="lblID3" runat="server" CssClass="InputHeader" meta:resourcekey="lblID3" />
            </div>

            <div class="roundedMain"><!--<![endif]-->

                <company:Control3 ID="control3Third" runat="server" meta:resourcekey="control3Third"
                    Filter="" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="id4">

            <%-- ID4 --%>
            <div class="roundedTop">
                <asp:Label ID="lblID4" runat="server" CssClass="InputHeader" meta:resourcekey="lblID4" />
            </div>

            <div class="roundedMain"><!--<![endif]-->

                <company:Control3 ID="control3Forth" runat="server" meta:resourcekey="control3Forth"
                    Filter="" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="id5">

            <%-- ID5 --%>
            <div class="roundedTop">
                <asp:Label ID="lblID5" runat="server" CssClass="InputHeader" meta:resourcekey="lblID5" />
            </div>

            <div class="roundedMain"><!--<![endif]-->

                <company:Control3 ID="control3Fifth" runat="server" meta:resourcekey="control3Fifth"
                    Filter="" />
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <asp:Timer ID="tUpdateTimer" runat="server" ontick="tUpdateTimer_Tick"></asp:Timer>

    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upTimer" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate />
        <Triggers><asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="tUpdateTimer" EventName="Tick" /></Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>

</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="JavascriptContent" runat="server">

    <script type="text/javascript">

        var tblSomething = null;
        var tblHostConnection = null;

        function pageLoad(sender, args) {
            attachDataTablesToSomethingTable();
            attachDataTablesToHostConnectionTable();
        }

        function attachDataTablesToSomethingTable() {
            tblSomething = $('#tblSomething').dataTable({
                "bRetrieve": true,
                "bServerSide": false,
                "bPaginate": false,
                "bFilter": false,
                "bSort": false,
                "bJQueryUI": true,
                "sScrollY": "230px",
                "sScrollX": "100%",
                "oLanguage": {
                    "sEmptyTable": '<%= GetLocalResourceObject("tblSomething.Empty").ToString() %>',
                    "sProcessing": '<img id="imgAnim" src="<%= ResolveUrl(Resources.SiteIcons.Loader) %>" />',
                    "sInfo":
                                '<%= GetLocalResourceObject("sInfo.Showing").ToString() %>' + ' _START_ ' +
                                '<%= GetLocalResourceObject("sInfo.to").ToString() %>' + ' _END_ ' +
                                '<%= GetLocalResourceObject("sInfo.of").ToString() %>' + ' _TOTAL_ ' +
                                '<%= GetLocalResourceObject("sInfo.entries").ToString() %>'
                }
            });
        }

        function attachDataTablesToHostConnectionTable() {
            tblHostConnection = $('#tblHostConnection').dataTable({
                "bRetrieve": true,
                "bServerSide": false,
                "bPaginate": false,
                "bFilter": false,
                "bSort": false,
                "bJQueryUI": true,
                "sScrollY": "100%",
                "sScrollX": "100%",
                "oLanguage": {
                    "sEmptyTable": '<%= GetLocalResourceObject("tblHostConnection.Empty").ToString() %>',
                    "sProcessing": '<img id="imgAnim" src="<%= ResolveUrl(Resources.SiteIcons.Loader) %>" />',
                    "sInfo": ''
                }
            });
        }

    </script>

</asp:Content>
```

From a bit of playing around, if I commented out `attachDataTablesToSomethingTable()` from the JavaScript call at the bottom, then no styling was applied to any table, so I assume that is the function that applies/calls the styling. Again, I am inexperienced with ASP.NET and JavaScript, so if anyone could shed any light, that would be awesome.

Comment: What are the contents of the CSS file?

Comment: The issue is the jquery plugin is only being applied to one table.  You need to look at the outputted html, and determine what elements contain the tables to wire up the plugin.

Comment: Would it be possible to call the plugin multiple times, or would this require changing the plugin itself?

Comment: I see no tables in the asp code you have provided

Comment: The table is the custom control. They get added with: "<company:Control3 ..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll agree with @lucuma's comment to your question. So, I may suggest you to implement unique id for table of each custom control instance. This can be achieved by implementing a public property say 'TableID' in your custom control, which can be configured for each custom control instance.

The below parts go into user custom control implementation:

Code behind:

```
public string TableID
{
   get;
   set;
}
```

Markup:

```
<table id='<%=TableID %>'>
```

Configure the TableID property for each custom control instance in aspx page:

```
<company:Control3 ID="control3First" runat="server" meta:resourcekey="control3First" Filter=""
TableID='mytable1' />

<company:Control3 ID="control3Second" runat="server" meta:resourcekey="control3Second" Filter=""
TableID='mytable2' />
```

And finally, wire up jquery plug-in for each table...

```
mytable1 = $('#mytable1').dataTable(...);
mytable2 = $('#mytable2').dataTable(...);
```

Hope this helps...